# Plotly Dash Table shows up in jupyter notebook but not in dash app?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have the following create table function, and it works accordingly in Jupyter Notebook, however when I call it out in the Dash app nothing renders.

```
def create_table(dataframe):
    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
    # header=dict(values=['A Scores', 'B Scores'],
    #             line_color='darkslategray',
    #             fill_color='lightskyblue',
    #             align='left'),
    cells=dict(values=[dataframe.columns.values.tolist(), # 1st column
                       df_cohort_3.iloc[0:1].values.tolist()[0]  # 2nd column
                      ],
               line_color='darkslategray',
               fill_color='lightcyan',
               align='left'))
                        ])
    #fig.update_layout(width=500, height=600)
    return fig.show()
```

Here is my Dash logic:

```
app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(style={'backgroundColor': colors['background']},
children=[

    #Title
    html.Div(html.H1(children="My Dashboard "))

    #Generate Dash table

    ,create_table(df_1)


    ,

                    ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False, port=3005)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your dataframe (`df_1`) properly loaded? Perhaps turn `debug` on and check the error report?

Answer (score 0):

Dash app do not use the fig.show(). It uses the fig object to generate the display. You do not need to call the .show() methode.

```
def create_table(dataframe):
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
cells=dict(values=[dataframe.columns.values.tolist(), # 1st column
                   df_cohort_3.iloc[0:1].values.tolist()[0]  # 2nd column
                  ],
           line_color='darkslategray',
           fill_color='lightcyan',
           align='left'))
                    ])
#fig.update_layout(width=500, height=600)
return fig
```

and then:

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(style={'backgroundColor': colors['background']},
children=[

    #Title
    html.Div(html.H1(children="My Dashboard "))

    #Generate Dash table

    ,dcc.Graph(figure=fig),


    ,

                    ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False, port=3005)
```